# How to store relations in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with a many-to-may relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // Some other fields

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "e1_e2",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "e1_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "e2_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }
    )
    private Set<Entity2> e2s = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters & setters

}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // Some other fields

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "e2s")
    private Set<Entity1> e1s = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters & setters

}
```

I have a webpage with a form for an `Entity2`. When I select some `Entity1`s from a multi-select and submit the form,
I can see inside the controller that all selected `Entity1`s are stored in `e1s`. Then I try to persist the new `Entity2` using `JpaRepository::save()`.
The `Entity2` gets persisted, but not the relations to `Entity1`. The `save()` call is wrapped in a service method that is annotated
with `@Transactional`. Why are the relations not persisted?

This is the controller method that receives the `Entity2`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createSupplier(@ModelAttribute final Entity2 e2) {
    service.create(e2);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

And the service method:

```
@Transactional
public Entity2 create(Entity2 e2) {
    return repository.save(e2);
}
```

Comment: Do you add `entity2`to the set `e2s`? and also the oposite? Show the service method

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading

Comment: first rule for using relation table... don't use them!

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Why? Can you give reasons for this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Change the annotation of e1s to `@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` in order to cascade the save operation to the related entities. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html

Comment: Suppose I have two `Entity2`s which both depend on the same `Entity1`. When I delete one `Entity2`, does it delete the `Entity1` too?